# Ireports with multiple filters

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm designing a report on Ireport with a SQL query, and I'm working with filters, basically I want to be able to compare a input parameter "shift" with a field in my report, so I can show my report by shift.

This part of the report works fine, I just used a filtering expression `$F{Shift}.equals( $P{shift} )`, however this only works with one shift, but I want to also be able to see all shifts in the same report. Is there a way to do this?

As @Pu297 suggested, I could use an IN comparation in my SQL query, but setting it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE shift IN P!{shift}
```

Where my shift ireport parameter is a `String` and I type it in the way `"1,2,3"` to show the first 3 shifts

Comment: Do you mean you want something like $F{Shift} IN ( $P{shift} ) ??

Comment: yes, but using $P{shift} on my query doesn't return anything, let me explain further on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQl Query

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE shift IN ($P!{shift})
```

And your input text should be

```
'1','2','3'
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked fine, but I opted for using the `$X{IN, table_field, parameter_name}` variable, which I read is made for IN statements, my final query looked like this: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ..conditions.. AND $X{IN, shift, Shift}`